# PHP Laravel get all question from question's table base on the foreign Key of vote's Table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

If I can I would like to be able to get all "*voted questions*" the questions authenticated user have **voted**. and return in a json format.

I want to get the questions  referenced from vote's table "*question_id*".

Questions Table:

```
id(PK)| title | description | created_at | updated_at
```

- **Question Model** hasMany votes

  ```
  class Question extends Model
  {
    public function votes()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Vote::class, 'question_id');
    }
  }
  ```

Votes Table:

```
id(PK) | answer_id(FK) | question_id(FK) | user_id(FK)
```

- **Vote Model** belongsTo a question

  ```
  class Vote extends Model
  {
    public function question()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Question::class, 'question_id');
    }
  }
  ```

**Filter Method**: Will return all the voted question alongside the votes (I only want the questions)

```
public function filtered()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $votes = Vote::with('question')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
        $votes->makeVisible('question');
        return response()->json($votes);
    }
```

I was able to get all the "voted questions" through Vote Model. but I would like to get only the question.

**Current Result** : votes with voted questions

```
 [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "question_id": 1,
        "answer_id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "question": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "a question this user voted",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question_id": 2,
        "answer_id": 3,
        "user_id": 1,
        "question": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "another question this user voted",
        }
    }
]
```

**Desired Result** : only voted questions

```
 [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "title": "a question this user voted",
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "title": "another question this user voted",
    }
]
```

is this possible? if not, any advice will be appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to reformat it that way?

Comment: when I request to get "all questions",  the response is formated like the "desired Result". so I would like the filtered format of "voted questions"  to be like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all votes for a user like so:

User.php

```
public function votes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Vote`);
}
```

And you can get all questions from votes like so:

Vote.php

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
}
```

Then you should be able to access all these relationships, and pluck the relevant values.

```
$user = Auth::user();
$userVotes = $user->votes()
    ->with('questions')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('question.id', 'question.title');
```

Comment: I modified it to " ->pluck('question') " to format it like the desired format. thanks a lot